# How do I resolve "Couldn't guess spec for root" errors reported by AML for JSON files

Tags: json, validation, mulesoft

I'm using the MuleSoft VSCode AML Support extension to validate RAML and OAS API specs. The extension also validates schema files and JSON files.

AML is reporting a problem with all JSON files in my project. But it is unclear what the issue is, and more of a concern, I can't find any information to resolve the issue.

The warning message reported for every JSON file in the project is:

`Couldn't guess spec for root file (http://a.ml/vocabularies/amf/parser#couldnt-guess-root)`

The error is reported for otherwise valid JSON files and even empty JSON files!

I suspect there must be some way of configuring what JSON Schema to use for validating JSON files within the project.  But I can't find that information anywhere.

Comment: Seems like a bug. The extension seems to be experimental. Since you already reported a bug https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/als-vscode/issues/61 I will recommend to wait an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

Initially, I opened a folder in VS Code and created this JSON file.
Next time when I wanted to excess file I opened it directly , so it throws an error `Couldn't guess spec for root file (http://a.ml/vocabularies/amf/parser#couldnt-guess-root)`

The error disaapeared when I opened the folder which was open at the time of creating the file.